# Function Arguments - difference between two methods of input

Tags: python, function, arguments, tuples

Fairly simple question but I'm relatively new to Python and working through the book Think Python. I'm on the chapter about tuples and have an exercise where I'm told to write a function which takes any number of arguments and returns their sum.

Writing this isn't a problem:

```
def sumall(*args):
    return sum(args)
print(sumall(1,2,3,4))
```

My question is why does the above work but the below doesn't?

```
sum(1,2,3,4)
```

I understand that sum() takes a maximum of 2 arguments, but what is the difference between that and assigning those arguments from the arguments put into the sumall() function?

Comment: `sum(args)` passes *one* argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) takes an `iterable` and optional start position, but you're passing in multiple integer arguments, which fails.

When you call `sum(args)` you're passing in the `args` list. When you call `sum(1, 2, 3, 4)` you're passing in 4 different integer arguments.

Comment: So my understanding of what you're saying is that when passed into sumall() the '1,2,3,4' is considered a tuple and is therefore iterable when then passed into sum()?

Comment: Pretty much. When you use args in that way, you have an iterable that you can pass to sum.